# Order by clause not behaving correctly after several joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, left-join

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `post_data`. * , pv.`seller_id` , pv.`islimited` , pv.`isquantity` , pv.`isslider`, `price`.`original_price` , `price`.`discount_percentage` , `timelimit`.`start_date` , `timelimit`.`expire_date` , `quantity`.`in_stock`, `currency`.`currency_symbol`, `seller`.`directory`, `post_to_cat`.`cat_id`, count(`sales`.`sales_id`) as sale FROM `post_view` AS pv
INNER JOIN `post_data` ON pv.`post_id` = `post_data`.`post_id` AND pv.`status` = 1 
INNER JOIN `price` ON pv.`post_id` = `price`.`post_id` 
INNER JOIN `currency` ON `price`.`currency_id` = `currency`.`currency_id` 
INNER JOIN `seller` ON pv.`seller_id` = `seller`.`seller_id` 
INNER JOIN `post_to_cat` ON `post_to_cat`.`cat_id` = 1 AND `post_to_cat`.`post_id` = `post_data`.`post_id` 
LEFT JOIN `timelimit` ON ( CASE WHEN pv.`islimited` = 1 THEN `timelimit`.`post_id` ELSE -1 END ) = pv.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `quantity` ON  ( CASE WHEN pv.`isquantity` = 1 THEN `quantity`.`post_id` ELSE -1 END ) = pv.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `sales` ON `sales`.`post_id` = pv.`post_id` AND `sales`.`status` = 1 
WHERE pv.`status` = 1
ORDER BY pv.`post_id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The `ORDER BY DESC` is not working, it just returns the first row from the table, but I want to get the highest post_id value row. What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: You have `count()` function and no `group by` it will have one only one row.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` what do you expect? it returns 1 row as you've asked.

Comment: Yeah But i expect from it to return last post added! as i am sorting desc by post_id

Comment: Why in your timelimit and quantity joins do you join to pv.post_id? That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Just to check if the post in `pv` is timelimited or not as i had bit 0 for no and 1 for yes. If there is any better option please let me know.

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to understand. I have given a suggestion. If it does not work, please post some sample data (preferably in an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and expected results so I can try to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is mostly as a result of preforming aggregation (using the COUNT()) function, without any group by. Although, it seems like you don't necessarily need it because you want that count only for the post in question.

If you're trying to gather all of that information for a single post, I would adjust your `WHERE` clause to have a condition to only gather that information for the post with the largest ID.

Instead of ordering by ID and limiting by 1, use a subquery to get the largest id, like this:

```
...
WHERE pv.status = 1 AND post_data.slug = 'abc' AND pv.post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM post_view);
```

Comment: Thanks @McAdam331 , Exactly matched to my need! :)

Comment: @king4aol not a problem, I'm glad it helped. If this is the solution you use, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will be able to see the solution to your problem.

Comment: I have doubt that this is correct solution. Even if the issue was correctly detected. You can change it at least to `WHERE post_data.slug = 'abc' AND pv.post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM post_view WHERE pv.status = 1);` But as you can see even this one will break the result if the last post_id is not joined to `post_data.slug = 'abc'`.

Comment: @Alex that's a very good catch. OP, can you try adding a `GROUP BY pv.post_id` and then order in descending order like you had originally, and see if that still works?

Comment: I did edit to my answer. Waiting for @king4aol test result I guess.

Answer (score 1):

AS @Alex said in the comments you've got a `LIMIT 1` at the end, you should probably bracket the last `LEFT JOIN` also for readability.

Comment: i used limit 1 to retrieve only 1 result. Is that have any effect upon the result??

Comment: Okay in your question it sounded like the problem was that you were only getting one result, I take it you want the highest post_id first and that's it?

Comment: Have you tried using `MAX(pv.post_id)` in your select statement and then grouping by the other columns? This would be the alternative at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As @McAdam331 said we need data sample and sql fiddle to investigate what is wrong with you query. But at the moment I have some suggestions how to improve and debug your query.

First off all, what do I see the main and very left table in your query is `post_view` so all other tables should be `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get the max id. You should use `INNER JOIN` only if you think that other table could *filter* your main table somehow and order or result could be *other table dependend*. But in your case I see no reason to use `INNER JOIN`.

Second point is your very weird `ON` conditions:

```
LEFT JOIN `timelimit` ON ( CASE WHEN pv.`islimited` = 1 THEN `timelimit`.`post_id` ELSE -1 END ) = pv.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `quantity` ON  ( CASE WHEN pv.`isquantity` = 1 THEN `quantity`.`post_id` ELSE -1 END ) = pv.`post_id`
```

I have converted them into another one

```
CASE WHEN pv.`islimited`=1 THEN `timelimit`.`start_date` ELSE NULL END as start_date ,
CASE WHEN pv.`islimited`=1 THEN `timelimit`.`expire_date` ELSE NULL END as expire_date,
CASE WHEN pv.`isquantity`=1 THEN  `quantity`.`in_stock` ELSE NULL END as in_stock,
```

But I still don't like it. It seems very useless to me. And has no sense when I read `CASE WHEN pv.islimited=1 THEN timelimit.start_date ELSE NULL END as start_date` so if flag `pv.islimited=0` you don't need `start_date`? Are you sure?

And the last thing I can suggest: try to use my or even your query. But add every table by step while debugging. So First query just:

```
SELECT 
pv.`post_id`, pv.`seller_id` , pv.`islimited` , pv.`isquantity` ,
pv.`isslider`
FROM `post_view` AS pv
WHERE pv.`status` = 1 
ORDER BY pv.`post_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If it returns correct `post_id` add next table:

```
SELECT 
pv.`post_id`, pv.`seller_id` , pv.`islimited` , pv.`isquantity` ,
pv.`isslider`, 
`post_data`. * 
FROM `post_view` AS pv
LEFT JOIN `post_data` 
ON pv.`post_id` = `post_data`.`post_id` 
WHERE pv.`status` = 1 
  AND `post_data`.`slug` = 'abc' 
ORDER BY pv.`post_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Check the result. And continue step by step.

Yes it takes time. But that is debugging process. It could be the fastest way to get that query done. :-)

```
SELECT `post_data`. * ,
pv.`post_id`, pv.`seller_id` , pv.`islimited` , pv.`isquantity` ,
pv.`isslider`, `price`.`original_price` , `price`.`discount_percentage` , 
CASE WHEN pv.`islimited`=1 THEN `timelimit`.`start_date` ELSE NULL END as start_date ,
CASE WHEN pv.`islimited`=1 THEN `timelimit`.`expire_date` ELSE NULL END as expire_date,
CASE WHEN pv.`isquantity`=1 THEN  `quantity`.`in_stock` ELSE NULL END as in_stock,
 `currency`.`currency_symbol`, `seller`.`directory`, `post_to_cat`.`cat_id`, count(`sales`.`sales_id`) as sale 
FROM `post_view` AS pv
LEFT JOIN `post_data` 
ON pv.`post_id` = `post_data`.`post_id` 
LEFT JOIN `price` 
ON pv.`post_id` = `price`.`post_id` 
LEFT JOIN `currency` 
ON `price`.`currency_id` = `currency`.`currency_id` 
LEFT JOIN `seller` 
ON pv.`seller_id` = `seller`.`seller_id` 
LEFT JOIN `post_to_cat` 
ON `post_to_cat`.`cat_id` = 1 
  AND `post_to_cat`.`post_id` = pv.`post_id` 
LEFT JOIN `timelimit` 
ON `timelimit`.`post_id` = pv.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `quantity` 
ON quantity`.`post_id` = pv.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `sales` 
ON `sales`.`post_id` = pv.`post_id` 
  AND `sales`.`status` = 1 
WHERE pv.`status` = 1 
  AND `post_data`.`slug` = 'abc' 
GROUP BY pv.`post_id` 
ORDER BY pv.`post_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

*EDIT 1* - last     `GROUP BY pv.post_id` was added as per @McAdam331 notice about `count()` function without `GROUP BY`

Comment: Problem is solved by @McAdam331. But your detailed suggestions are really appreciable and will be helpful for me in this and further upcoming problems may be. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes I see. Check my comment under his answer. Just to be sure that it resolved your issue completely. and good luck with your project :-)

Comment: These are all really great points, some I didn't even think of. And Alex is right, @king4aol, while my query may have worked in this individual case, it has some potential flaws that you might see in the future. If this is for a project of any kind that you're going to continue to use in the future, I would be sure to do some testing now rather than wait for it to break.